# Create a list from statements in a DSL block

Tags: kotlin

In an attempt to build a DSL for validation, I am looking for ways to collect the statements inside a block/lambda with receiver. To illustrate, here is a minimal example without the actual validation logic:

```
data class Constraint(val hint: String)

class Validation(val constraints: List<Constraint>) {

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(init: (ValidationBuilder.() -> Unit)): Validation {
            return ValidationBuilder().apply(init).build()
        }
    }

    class ValidationBuilder {
        private var constraints: MutableList<Constraint> = mutableListOf()

        operator fun Constraint.unaryPlus() {
            constraints.add(this)
        }

        fun build() = Validation(constraints)
    }
}
```

This can then be used to build a Validation like so

```
val validation = Validation {
    +Constraint("First constraint")
    val secondConstraintHint = "Second constraint"
    +Constraint(secondConstraintHint)
}
```

I would like to get rid of the `unaryPlus` operator and directly collect the individual statements in the block that are evaluated to a `Constraint` so that I can do something like:

```
val validation = Validation {
    Constraint("First constraint")
    val secondConstraintHint = "Second constraint"
    Constraint(secondConstraintHint)
}
```

Is that possible somehow?

To give a little bit more context, the actual result I am aiming for will look more like this:

```
Validation<User> {
    User::firstName {
        val min = 2
        minLength(min) hint "Please provide a first name"
        maxLength(200) // uses default hint
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there seems to be no straightforward solution, because Kotlin provides no way to handle an evaluated expression result that is not assigned, returned or passed anywhere.

A possible workaround is to mimic the constructor you need with a function defined for your builder:

```
class ValidationBuilder {
    /* ... */

    fun Constraint(name: String) = 
        full.qualified.name.of.Constraint(name).also(constraints::add)
}
```

Unfortunately, this will require you to duplicate all the signatures that you want to call in this way.

---

**UPD (answering to the comment)**: I believe the idiomatic way for users to customize a DSL is defining their own extensions for the DSL builders:

```
fun ValidationBuilder.nonEmptyText(min: Int = 1, max: Int = 65.536) = TODO()
```

If a `Constraint` that comes from outside the DSL is an important use case, you can cover it with a special function (e.g. `fun ValidationBuilder.constraint(...)`) and let the users delegate their extensions to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately that isn't practical because additional Constraints can be defined by the user and should be usable in the DSL e.g. a user could define a `fun nonEmptyText(min: Int = 1, max: Int = 65.536): Constraint` factory method to create a constraint and will not be able to add the shadowing function in the `ValidationBuilder`

Comment: @n_l, I think a Kotlin DSL customization on a user's side is usually done with DSL-specific extensions. Updated the answer.